# Why is Inrush current important to me when buying a power supply?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inrush-current

I am in the process of buying some power supplies and was looking over the datasheet at saw the inrush current is stated as "Coldstart 80A/230VAC"

I can also see that the AC Input is rated 1.1A/230VAC.

Now I know that the rated 1.1A determines how much the power supply could potentially draw during operation. But I do not understand the inrush rating. I know that inrush current happens at startup very very briefly. But I a bit terrified by the 80Amp rating.

How should I understand this rating if I what to plug it is not a normal wall socket at home?

And does it have even more serious meaning if I plugged 5 of the same one into the same wall socket?

For reference here is the  complete datasheet for the power supply:
http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=UHP-200(R)#1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inrush-current listed is worst case. That is, when you happen to turn it on when the AC voltage is at the peak of a cycle and when any internal inrush circuitry is already heated. You will likely draw a lot less most of the time you turn it on.

The in-rush current dissipates extremely quickly, and assuming you don't have really fast fuses or circuit breakers, it "should" not present a problem.

However, I would avoid installing a number of these power supplies on a bus-bar and switching them all on simultaneously with the bus bar switch.

Comment: Ahh okay. I believe that I have slow fuses. I had some other power supplies that had a 40A/230VAC incurrent rush rating and I have 4-5 on one circuit that I could turn on and off without issue.

So basically if I have slow fuses this shouldn't be a problem, but it would be wise to turn all my power supplies on one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The above information about the inrush current by itself, while useful, is not enough for the selection of a fuse since it does not give any additional detail about the time pattern of that current peak (in other words, the time to load power supply input capacitor), but if this fuse is of the type "fast acting" this should be considered. In shorts, it is just a complementary data in the product specification.